# Pimcore: New product class not visible in e-commerce product list

Tags: pimcore

**Goal**

Data objects of my data object class `Product` should be visible in the e-commerce Pimcore site.

**Current Setup**

- Current Demo and Blue Print Application for Pimcore
- I create a new data object class called `Product`. Parent PHP class is set to `\App\Model\Product\AbstractProduct` (Complete class definition export attached)
- Created a new data object based on the `Product` class.

**Result**

The new product is not visible in the shop. There is no error shown up either.

**What I also tried**

Based on the Index Service documentation I manually updated the index, without any effect.

```
$ php bin/console ecommerce:indexservice:bootstrap --update-index
Processing 1 Product in segments of 50, batches of 50, 1 round, 1 batch in 1 process

 1/1 [============================] 100% < 1 sec/< 1 sec 48.5 MiB

Processed 1 Product.
```

**Attached complete class definition export**

```
{
    "id": "PROD",
    "description": "",
    "modificationDate": 1669880184,
    "parentClass": "\\App\\Model\\Product\\AbstractProduct",
    "implementsInterfaces": "",
    "listingParentClass": "",
    "useTraits": "",
    "listingUseTraits": "",
    "allowInherit": true,
    "allowVariants": true,
    "showVariants": true,
    "layoutDefinitions": {
        "name": "pimcore_root",
        "type": null,
        "region": null,
        "title": null,
        "width": 0,
        "height": 0,
        "collapsible": false,
        "collapsed": false,
        "bodyStyle": null,
        "datatype": "layout",
        "permissions": null,
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "Layout",
                "type": null,
                "region": null,
                "title": "",
                "width": "",
                "height": "",
                "collapsible": false,
                "collapsed": false,
                "bodyStyle": "",
                "datatype": "layout",
                "permissions": null,
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "Base Data",
                        "type": null,
                        "region": null,
                        "title": "Base Data",
                        "width": "",
                        "height": "",
                        "collapsible": false,
                        "collapsed": false,
                        "bodyStyle": "",
                        "datatype": "layout",
                        "permissions": null,
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "name": "productName",
                                "title": "Product Name",
                                "tooltip": "",
                                "mandatory": true,
                                "noteditable": false,
                                "index": true,
                                "locked": false,
                                "style": "",
                                "permissions": null,
                                "datatype": "data",
                                "fieldtype": "input",
                                "relationType": false,
                                "invisible": false,
                                "visibleGridView": false,
                                "visibleSearch": false,
                                "width": "",
                                "defaultValue": null,
                                "columnLength": 190,
                                "regex": "",
                                "regexFlags": [],
                                "unique": true,
                                "showCharCount": false,
                                "defaultValueGenerator": ""
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "localizedfields",
                                "title": "",
                                "tooltip": "",
                                "mandatory": false,
                                "noteditable": false,
                                "index": null,
                                "locked": false,
                                "style": "",
                                "permissions": null,
                                "datatype": "data",
                                "fieldtype": "localizedfields",
                                "relationType": false,
                                "invisible": false,
                                "visibleGridView": true,
                                "visibleSearch": true,
                                "children": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "description",
                                        "title": "Description",
                                        "tooltip": "",
                                        "mandatory": false,
                                        "noteditable": false,
                                        "index": false,
                                        "locked": false,
                                        "style": "",
                                        "permissions": null,
                                        "datatype": "data",
                                        "fieldtype": "textarea",
                                        "relationType": false,
                                        "invisible": false,
                                        "visibleGridView": false,
                                        "visibleSearch": false,
                                        "width": "",
                                        "height": "",
                                        "maxLength": null,
                                        "showCharCount": false,
                                        "excludeFromSearchIndex": false
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "packaging",
                                        "title": "Packaging",
                                        "tooltip": "",
                                        "mandatory": false,
                                        "noteditable": false,
                                        "index": false,
                                        "locked": false,
                                        "style": "",
                                        "permissions": null,
                                        "datatype": "data",
                                        "fieldtype": "input",
                                        "relationType": false,
                                        "invisible": false,
                                        "visibleGridView": false,
                                        "visibleSearch": false,
                                        "width": "",
                                        "defaultValue": null,
                                        "columnLength": 190,
                                        "regex": "",
                                        "regexFlags": [],
                                        "unique": false,
                                        "showCharCount": false,
                                        "defaultValueGenerator": ""
                                    }
                                ],
                                "region": null,
                                "layout": null,
                                "width": "",
                                "height": "",
                                "maxTabs": null,
                                "border": false,
                                "provideSplitView": false,
                                "tabPosition": null,
                                "hideLabelsWhenTabsReached": null,
                                "fieldDefinitionsCache": null,
                                "permissionView": null,
                                "permissionEdit": null,
                                "labelWidth": 0,
                                "labelAlign": "left"
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "image",
                                "title": "Image",
                                "tooltip": "",
                                "mandatory": false,
                                "noteditable": false,
                                "index": false,
                                "locked": false,
                                "style": "",
                                "permissions": null,
                                "datatype": "data",
                                "fieldtype": "image",
                                "relationType": false,
                                "invisible": false,
                                "visibleGridView": false,
                                "visibleSearch": false,
                                "width": "",
                                "height": "",
                                "uploadPath": ""
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "group",
                                "title": "Group",
                                "tooltip": "",
                                "mandatory": false,
                                "noteditable": false,
                                "index": false,
                                "locked": false,
                                "style": "",
                                "permissions": null,
                                "datatype": "data",
                                "fieldtype": "manyToOneRelation",
                                "relationType": true,
                                "invisible": false,
                                "visibleGridView": false,
                                "visibleSearch": false,
                                "classes": [
                                    {
                                        "classes": "ProductGroup"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "pathFormatterClass": "",
                                "width": "",
                                "assetUploadPath": "",
                                "objectsAllowed": true,
                                "assetsAllowed": false,
                                "assetTypes": [],
                                "documentsAllowed": false,
                                "documentTypes": []
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "categories",
                                "title": "Categories",
                                "tooltip": "",
                                "mandatory": false,
                                "noteditable": false,
                                "index": false,
                                "locked": false,
                                "style": "",
                                "permissions": null,
                                "datatype": "data",
                                "fieldtype": "manyToManyObjectRelation",
                                "relationType": true,
                                "invisible": false,
                                "visibleGridView": false,
                                "visibleSearch": false,
                                "classes": [
                                    {
                                        "classes": "Category"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "pathFormatterClass": "",
                                "width": "",
                                "height": "",
                                "maxItems": null,
                                "visibleFields": "id,fullpath,name",
                                "allowToCreateNewObject": false,
                                "optimizedAdminLoading": false,
                                "enableTextSelection": false,
                                "visibleFieldDefinitions": []
                            }
                        ],
                        "locked": false,
                        "fieldtype": "panel",
                        "layout": null,
                        "border": false,
                        "icon": "",
                        "labelWidth": 0,
                        "labelAlign": "left"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Attributes",
                        "type": null,
                        "region": null,
                        "title": "Attributes",
                        "width": "",
                        "height": "",
                        "collapsible": false,
                        "collapsed": false,
                        "bodyStyle": "",
                        "datatype": "layout",
                        "permissions": null,
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "name": "attributes",
                                "title": "Attributes",
                                "tooltip": "",
                                "mandatory": false,
                                "noteditable": false,
                                "index": false,
                                "locked": false,
                                "style": "",
                                "permissions": null,
                                "datatype": "data",
                                "fieldtype": "objectbricks",
                                "relationType": false,
                                "invisible": false,
                                "visibleGridView": false,
                                "visibleSearch": false,
                                "allowedTypes": [
                                    "EdgebandingAttributes"
                                ],
                                "maxItems": null,
                                "border": false
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "saleInformation",
                                "title": "Sale Information",
                                "tooltip": "",
                                "mandatory": false,
                                "noteditable": false,
                                "index": false,
                                "locked": false,
                                "style": "",
                                "permissions": null,
                                "datatype": "data",
                                "fieldtype": "objectbricks",
                                "relationType": false,
                                "invisible": false,
                                "visibleGridView": false,
                                "visibleSearch": false,
                                "allowedTypes": [
                                    "SaleInformation"
                                ],
                                "maxItems": null,
                                "border": false
                            }
                        ],
                        "locked": false,
                        "fieldtype": "panel",
                        "layout": null,
                        "border": false,
                        "icon": "",
                        "labelWidth": 0,
                        "labelAlign": "left"
                    }
                ],
                "locked": false,
                "fieldtype": "tabpanel",
                "border": false,
                "tabPosition": null
            }
        ],
        "locked": false,
        "fieldtype": "panel",
        "layout": null,
        "border": false,
        "icon": null,
        "labelWidth": 100,
        "labelAlign": "left"
    },
    "icon": "",
    "previewUrl": "",
    "group": "Product Data",
    "showAppLoggerTab": false,
    "linkGeneratorReference": "",
    "previewGeneratorReference": "",
    "compositeIndices": [],
    "generateTypeDeclarations": true,
    "showFieldLookup": false,
    "propertyVisibility": {
        "grid": {
            "id": true,
            "key": false,
            "path": true,
            "published": true,
            "modificationDate": true,
            "creationDate": true
        },
        "search": {
            "id": true,
            "key": false,
            "path": true,
            "published": true,
            "modificationDate": true,
            "creationDate": true
        }
    },
    "enableGridLocking": false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it to work (after my last answer which was supposed to be a comment, my bad :D )

did you check the following:

### 1 Class override

https://pimcore.com/docs/pimcore/current/Development_Documentation/Extending_Pimcore/Overriding_Models.html

in /config/ecommerce/base-ecommerce.yaml

```
pimcore:
models:
    class_overrides:
        Pimcore\Model\DataObject\YourClass: App\Model\Product\YourClass
```

make sure you clear the cache like in the documentation

```
./bin/console cache:clear --no-warmup && ./bin/console pimcore:cache:clear
```

### 2 Check all Car Class names in Model / Controller

For example:

- src/controller/productController.php
- src/Model/Adminstyle/Car --> to your Class
- src/Model/Car --> to your Class

### 3 Make sure that saving a product of yours gets in the index

I saw that on saving the object in the backend, i got a log that the object was not indexed.

https://pimcore.com/docs/pimcore/current/Development_Documentation/E-Commerce_Framework/Index_Service/Product_Index_Configuration/Data_Architecture_and_Indexing_Process.html

I had some other issues which where 100% not meant to be fixed like i did. So try how far you come with this

edit: typo